# What accommodations must be made to boot an external HDD on multiple computers?

Tags: linux, usb, external-hdd

Is there a way to create a bootable external hard drive (like a persistent USB) that can be booted to multiple computers?

I have built plenty of live USBs where this wasn't a problem, but when I recently created a bootable external hard drive, it worked fine on the computer it was originally created on, but failed to boot on another.

Could this have something to do with fstab/grub pointing to /dev/sdb instead of an explicit uuid?

My previous setup involved:
SATA to USB or eSATA (I was only using the USB to boot)
Arch linux with LVM on LUKS for encryption and Grub to Bootload.

Grub never even appears to start on my alternate system.

Comment: Where did you install the boot sector on the original computer? Have you started that original computer without any of the original internal discs connected?

Comment: Boot sector was set at /dev/sdb1 unencrypted ofcourse. The root, home, and swap were set on an encrypted partition at /dev/sdb2. And no, I haven't tried to disconnect the other internal disks. My intent is to be able to run this ontop/in lieu of the systems already in place.

Comment: If sdb1 is the external drive, then you probably have different boot order on the other computers. An external SATA drive is less easy to boot, as the device naming in many bioses change when you add another SATA drive (but not when adding a USB).

Comment: My sata enclosure (that I'm booting from) has eSATA and USB outs, I've only been using the USB out: http://goo.gl/g66DIB when I boot up, in bios my connection registers as a generic usb device

Comment: In the other computers, it should be sufficient to give booting from USB in the BIOS higher priority than the internal HD.

Comment: Well... Here I was about to tell you how obvious that reply is, that "ofcourse I know how to boot a usb..." but then I go into bios and realize that is definitely part of the problem. That allowed me to boot grub. But now I'm getting another issue. It can't find the location of my encrypted volume now. I'm getting an error similar to the one I had on my Lvm-on-luks thread, except it's reading: ERROR: device '/dev/mapper/lvmpool-root' not found...

Comment: This is odd: I look in /dev to see if I can find out why i'm not seeing my partitions, oddly I don't have multiple sd entries... instead of the expected sda1,2,3 and sdb1,2,3,4 I see sda1,2,3,4,5,6,7...

Comment: That is strange, have you looked into using a UUID instead of `/dev/sdb2` as `cryptdevice=` parameter? I'am not sure if that is allowed, but it would make things portable, independent of drive and controller behaviour.

Comment: I haven't looked into it, but I think you're on to something. Persistent block device naming would help solve the issue of dynamic naming of my partitions as I go from computer to computer. Thanks again Anthon, I'll post my results when after I update.